# Check if date is expired SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How I can fix this SQL query to check if a date is older than the actual and is expired and can be deleted?

I've tried with this code but it seems not work

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
      $d = $date->format('Y-m-d');
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM test_table WHERE _out = ? AND _out <= {$d}");
      $stmt->execute(array($d)); 
?>
```

I've also tried with this query but when the ajax call is made to the controller it seems not work

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM reservations WHERE check_out <= {$d}");
```

Comment: What class are you using? PDO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading with attention the SQLite documentations I discovered that the best way to achieve my task is to use the `date()` function inside the query. I'm not too experienced with this database type. So here is how I fixed the issue

```
 <?php
   $stmt = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM test_table WHERE _out <= date()');
   $stmt->execute();
 ?>
```

Comment: oh you wanted to delete records older than today. I thought you wanted to just delete records older than a variable

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães yes sir, I didn't know that `PDO` with the SQLite 3 driver treat this kind of query differently than the traditional mysqli, thank you for the support

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$d = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM reservations WHERE check_out <= :out');
$stmt->bindValue(':out', 1, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Use ? for the replacement value and pass the valur in the execute method.

Comment: I'm on SQLite so can be this the problem?

Comment: youre using SQLite3 class then?

Comment: Yes, maybe I found a solution. I usually use mysql as database so the query I was using is correct and works without problems. In SQLite 3 I discovered that I need to use the date() inside the query to achieve the task. I'm not experienced on SQLite. Thanks for the support

Comment: You actually don't need to. Sqlite allows you to compare the dates as strings. The issue is that you are using PDO sintax to prepare a SQLite3 class. Ill update my answer with the correct code